# PreparedStatement alternative within JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am new to JPA, I used to used prepared statement in JDBC. Is there alternative to be used within JPA ? as there is a query which I call frequently

see this for info about prepared statment http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

thanks in advance,,,

Comment: Suggest that you read up on JPA first and such a question would be answered in the most basic JPA tutorial ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JPA way is [`EntityManager#createQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) with **named parameters** in [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) (examples in [this chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html)).

Comment: After 3 years, Thanks Balus

Answer (score 3):

The Java Persistence API provides a Query API to create dynamic queries and named queries. The Query method `setParameter` binds an argument to a parameter (both named queries and dynamic queries can use named parameters as well as positional parameters, you just can't mix both types of parameters).

Have a look at [Creating Queries Using the Java Persistence Query Language](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html) in tha Java eE 6 tutorial for examples.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? =)

If you have a statement which you use rather often, wouldn't that be a good reason to put it in a method in a session bean/DAO?

Comment: JPA doesn't use statements though. It uses queries and named queries.